# How can one direct traffic through tor when using terminal in ubuntu

Tags: tor

I'm using Ubuntu with tor browser and would like to direct all traffic through tor, most specifically redirecting ALL traffic from terminal through tor?

Comment: google it, I found something but lost it. IDK where it is